# How to rewrite tomcat served relative links in nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I'm looking to serve a tomcat webapp through nginx, and I have the home page working fine.
However, the links from the home page contain relative links that were served up in tomcat.
Is it possible to remove a known string from this relative link.

e.g.

new.site.com - Home page
proxies to localhost:8080/myapp/newsite

But this then contain this as an example link:
new.site.com/myapp/newsite/about

I'd like to be able to remove the 'myapp/newsite/' from the URLs.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue using the sub_filter module to rewrite content in nginx.conf